# Bounded Type Parameters in Static Method

Tags: java, generics

Are these two methods equivalent?

```
public static <T extends com.google.protobuf.Message> Any pack(T message) {}
public static Any pack(com.google.protobuf.Message message) {}
```

My understanding is that in the first function, T only applies to that static method, not other static methods or the class. Thus, it just restraint the input parameter to be a subtype of Message. Is that so? If this is the case, are these two methods equivalent?

Comment: If you don't do anything with `T` (e.g. use it as a return value), then yes, they are equal.

Comment: Note that generics are invariant. So if you *would* use something like `List<T>` versus `List<Message>`, they would be different. But in this case, where you don't, there is effectively no difference. There might be some subtle differences in terms of overloading and best-match for the compiler though, but those are probably irrelevant edge cases to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these two signatures are equivalent, assuming that the caller does not provide an explicit type witness. This is because, without a type witness, both signatures accept the same sets of arguments:

- Any argument that is accepted by the first signature must be an instance of `T`, and `T` is a subtype of `Message`, so the argument must also be an instance of `Message`, and is accepted by the second signature
- Any argument that is accepted by the second signature must be an instance of `Message`, and so can be accepted by the first signature if `T` is chosen to be `Message`